# How many times does array appear in another array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. This question seems to be answered in other programming languages but not RoR.

I have an array with 3 items in it.

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

I then have items in another array which i want to check and see how many times `array1` appear in `array2`:

```
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 10, 11, 2, 12, 3]
```

Answer should be 2.

Comment: Hmmm, your description is confusing, array1 appears 0 times inside array2, what appears 2 times in array2 are the elements of array1. Does it matter if they are not found in the same order? what happens if you find `1,2,1,2,3,3`? does that count as 1 or 2? what about `3,2,1`? you have to properly define what you mean with `appear in` for all possible cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
a1.map { |a1i| a2.count(a1i) }.min
```

which is calculating how frequently each item in `array1` appears in `array2` and then fetching the minimum count as the number of possible subarrays without intersections.

A sketchy representation of what my perception of @Stefan's suggestion is:

```
a1.product([0]).to_h.merge(
  a2.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)
).values_at(*a1).min
```

And a more reasonable one:

```
count_per_a2i = a2.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)
a1.map { |a1i| count_per_a2i[a1i] }.min_by(&:to_i)
```

Comment: You could also build a frequency hash to avoid traversing the array multiple times.

Comment: Could you expand your comment with an example Stephan?

Comment: to add to my issues the environment i am writing these scripts in doesn't have all the features i need to run these some of these answers. BUT saying that @potashin's first map suggestion worked fine :)

Comment: I'd use `a2.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] += 1 }.values_at(*a1).min`

Comment: @Marcin, perhaps `..values_at(*a1).min_by(&:to_i)`.

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej the hash hash has a default value of `0`, so you'd get `[0, 1, 2].min`

Comment: @Stefan ... obviously :)

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:

```
array2.each_with_object(array1.product([0]).to_h) do |el, hash|
  hash[el] += 1 if hash.key?(el)
end.each_value.min
```

Loops through array2 once, counts the elements we're interested in, selects the minimum value.

Used

```
array1.product([0]).to_h
 => {1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0}
```

to seed starting counters.

Answer (score 1):

Just like @stefan mentioned in comments to one of the posts.

> You could also build a frequency hash to avoid traversing the array multiple times.

What that means is:

```
frequency_map = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = 0 }

array2.each{ |number| frequency_map[number] += 1 }

frequency_map
#=> {1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>2, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>1, 7=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1, 10=>1, 11=>1, 12=>1}
```

As you can see above, we have the frequency of each number in array2 from only one iteration, i.e. O(n) time, but has O(n) space complexity.

From the above frequency, we can easily deduce the number of times `array1` appeared in `array2`:

```
frequency_of_array1 = nil
array1.each do |number|
  if frequency_of_array1.nil?
    frequency_of_array1 = frequency_map[number]
  else
    frequency_of_array1 = frequency_of_array1 > frequency_map[number] ? frequency_map[number] : frequency_of_array1
  end
end

frequency_of_array1 #=> 2
```

Or simply this(but build another array/space - which was avoided above):

```
array1.map{ |num| frequency_map[num] }.min
```

Comment: As shown in @Stefan's latter comment you only need a hash with a default value of zero, not a hash with a default proc.

Comment: @CarySwoveland :  There are n-ways for achieving one goal in Ruby. :)